# Can I delete a forked repository after Pull Request is merged without losing my contribution history?

Tags: github

I've forked a GitHub repository to contribute to the parent repo. Once I made the changes and the PR is merged, can I delete the forked repo?

Will deleting the forked repository

- delete my contribution in my profile for that PR?
- cause my contribution activity (my commits) to not show up on my profile?
- remove me from the list of contributors?

I found this blog post ([*Tidying up after Pull Requests*](https://github.blog/2012-12-03-tidying-up-after-pull-requests/)
) which talks about deleting a branch after the PR is merged, but couldn't find any article for forked contributions.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can delete the repository from your account.

It will not affect your contribution & your commits to that repository.

Comment: Wil the contribution activity still show the commits in my profile?

Comment: If you delete the project, there will be no effect on the parent repo as its already merged. Your contribution activity will be shown to their repo. I am not sure about your profile.

Answer (score 8):

If you deleted the forked repo whose PR was merged your **Profile badges & status remains the same.**
Contribution activity also remains same before.[image]

Comment: So, after deleting the fork repository, if my mind change and I want to contribute again so I need to fork the repository again?

Comment: Yes you have to fork it again.